# You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode

Tags: android, react-native, flutter

I'm trying to upload my AAB file to Google Play Store, i follow this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android for generating .aab file, but i'm getting this error **You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode.**

Comment: It means while you are signing your APK you are in debug mode instead of Release mode,

Comment: Have you followed these steps : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#adding-signing-config-to-your-apps-gradle-config

Comment: s i follow this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#adding-signing-config-to-your-apps-gradle-config but i am getting error You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode. while AAb file upload to play-store

Comment: are you using android studio?

Answer (score 37):

In android/app/build.gradle

```
 buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

change to

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it for me, removing the line "signingConfig signingConfigs.debug" that came in that block out-of-the-box was what was breaking it for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

This is an issue for Flutter as well as React Native. To state it more briefly, the **release** block of **buildTypes** in **android/app/build.gradle** needs to include `signingConfigs.release`, *not* `signingConfigs.debug`.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

This is shown in the Flutter [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android), but it isn't clearly stated. I've seen two people miss it in the last day.

`minifyEnabled` and `proguardFiles` are not required unless you need those options.